# Complex numbers iff proof

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I let $z_{0}=i$, $z_{1}=1+i$, and for $n \geq2$, defines $z_{n}=z_{n-1}z_{n-2}$. Prove for every non-negative integer n, $Re(z_{n})Im(z_{n})=0$if and only if $3|n$.

What is the best way to do it? I want to use de moivre theorem, but how is it exactly? Is the question for induction, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z_n=r_ne^{ia_n\frac{\pi}{4}}$, we see $z_0=e^{i2\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}}$, $z_1=\sqrt 2 e^{i 1\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}}$, so $a_0=2$, $a_1=1$. In general,
$$
z_n=z_{n-1}z_{n-2}=r_{n-1}e^{ia_{n-1}\frac{\pi}{4}}
 r_{n-2}e^{ia_{n-2}\frac{\pi}{4}}
=r_{n-1}r_{n-2}e^{i(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})\frac{\pi}{4}},
$$
so $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. Now $a_0=2$, $a_1=1$,
$a_2=3$, $a_3=4$, we prove by induction $a_n$ is even if and only if $n=3k$. Assume this is true
up to $n=3k$, especially $a_{3k}$ even, $a_{3k-1}$ odd. Then $a_{3k+1}=a_{3k}+a_{3k-1}$ is even plus odd so is odd, $a_{3k+2}=a_{3k+1}+a_{3k}$ is odd plus even so is odd, $a_{3k+3}=a_{3k+2}+a_{3k+1}$ is odd plus odd so is even. That concludes the induction.

Now if $3|n$, $a_n$ is even, write $a_n=2m$, so
$$
z_n=r_ne^{i(2m)\frac{\pi}{4}}=r_ne^{im\pi/2},
$$
if $m$ is even this is real (so $Im z_n=0$); and if $m$ is odd then this is pure imaginary (so $Re z_n=0$). In any case $(Im z_n)(Re z_n)=0$.